# Calling code after {{#each}} has rendered in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to call some code after an Ember `{{#each}}` tag has finished looping through its items. I have seen other questions that looked similar and the answer always implemented `didInsertElement` on the view. This does not seem to work for me as I am trying to access html objects that are not rendered with the view because they are in the `{{#each}}`.

Here is what my html looks like.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="user">
  {{#if isEditing}}
    <div class="well">
    {{partial 'user/edit'}}
    <button {{action 'doneEditing'}} class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
    <button {{action 'cancelEditing'}} class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
    </div>
  {{else}}
    <button {{action 'edit'}} class="btn btn-default">Edit</button>
  {{/if}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="user/edit">
  {{#view 'editor'}}
    <div id="sList" class="btn-group-vertical" role="group">
      {{#each s in model}}
        <button class="btn btn-default">
        {{s.theme}}
        </button>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  {{/view}}
</script>
```

And my javascript

```
App.UserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.all('strength')
  }
});

App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isEditing: false,  
  actions: {
    edit: function(){
      this.set("isEditing", true);
    },
    doneEditing: function(){
      this.set("isEditing", false);  
    },
    cancelEditing: function(){
      this.set("isEditing", false);
    }
  }
});

App.EditorView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    //Do something to the button elements
  }
});
```

When I try to run this, as soon as I hit the edit button and the partial loads, I get an error in the console after `didInsertElement` tried to access the button elements. It as if the elements in the div have not rendered yet. So how can I tell if the `{{#each}}` is done inserting elements into the html? I know this may be confusing but any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: If you can get this into a jsbin to illustrate your problem - that would really help us help you :)

Comment: what are you trying to do to the button? more likely than not, you can avoid direct DOM manipulation with more idiomatic Ember

Comment: Also along the lines of @sunrize920's suggestion, you may be able to use a jQuery delegate in `didInsertElement`, but you didn't post enough context for me to tell if that's the right solution for you.  A delegate will listen for events on a selector, even if they're added to the DOM after the delegate was created.

Answer (score 0):

Schedule your code in the afterRender queue to run after the contents of the view has been rendered.

```
App.EditorView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement: function() {
    Ember.run.schedule('afterRender', function() {
      this.$().find('button').each(function() {
        // $(this) is a button in this function
      });
    }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

Comment: explain what is your solution; do not just past codes